# Showing or Hiding a form(s) on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am working on a question and answer site and there is something that is troubling me.
I have a page where the candidates can attempt for a test based on the subject in which they are majoring.
So, when a candidate selects a subject, the form (in which the questions are) should be visible and all other forms should be hidden (I have multiple forms in one page). This section should be the size of that form (like I am using an iframe, I have noticed that even if keep one form visible, the page still consumes space as if all other form were visible).

By default I have a div block with some contents in it.

Here is my code :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Questions</title>
</head>
<body>
<br /><br />
<input type="radio" name="mathematics" onselect="func(1)" /> Mathematics
<input type="radio" name="physics" onselect="func(2)" /> Physics
<input type="radio" name="chemistry" onselect="func(3)" /> Chemistry
<input type="radio" name="biology" onselect="func(4)" /> Biology
<div id="content">
<p>Some contents</p>
<br /><br /><br />
<hr />
<div>
<form name="first" style="visibility:hidden;>
<ul type="none">
<li style="margin-bottom:15px; font-size:20px">1. What is the formula for     force</li>
    <li style="margin-bottom:15px"> 
        <ul type="none">
            <li style="  font-size:20px; float:left"><input type="radio" name="q1op"/></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; float:left;" >Option 1</li>
            <li style=" font-size:20px; float:left; margin-left:30px"><input type="radio" name="q1op" /></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; float:left" >Option 2</li>
            <li style=" font-size:20px; float:left; margin-left:30px"><input type="radio" name="q1op" /></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; float:left" >Option 3</li>
            <li style=" font-size:20px; float:left; margin-left:30px"><input type="radio" name="q1op" /></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; margin-bottom:15px;" >Option 4</li>
        </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</form>
<form name="second" style="visibility:hidden;>
<ul type="none">
    <li style="margin-bottom:15px; font-size:20px">1. What is the formula for force</li>
    <li style="margin-bottom:15px"> 
        <ul type="none">
            <li style="  font-size:20px; float:left"><input type="radio" name="q1op"/></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; float:left;" >Option 1</li>
            <li style=" font-size:20px; float:left; margin-left:30px"><input type="radio" name="q1op" /></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; float:left" >Option 2</li>
            <li style=" font-size:20px; float:left; margin-left:30px"><input type="radio" name="q1op" /></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; float:left" >Option 3</li>
            <li style=" font-size:20px; float:left; margin-left:30px"><input type="radio" name="q1op" /></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; margin-bottom:15px;" >Option 4</li>
        </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</form>
<form name="third" style="visibility:hidden;>
<ul type="none">
    <li style="margin-bottom:15px; font-size:20px">1. What is the formula for force</li>
    <li style="margin-bottom:15px"> 
        <ul type="none">
            <li style="  font-size:20px; float:left"><input type="radio" name="q1op"/></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; float:left;" >Option 1</li>
            <li style=" font-size:20px; float:left; margin-left:30px"><input type="radio" name="q1op" /></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; float:left" >Option 2</li>
            <li style=" font-size:20px; float:left; margin-left:30px"><input type="radio" name="q1op" /></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; float:left" >Option 3</li>
            <li style=" font-size:20px; float:left; margin-left:30px"><input type="radio" name="q1op" /></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; margin-bottom:15px;" >Option 4</li>
        </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</form>
<form name="fourth" style="visibility:hidden;">
<ul type="none">
    <li style="margin-bottom:15px; font-size:20px">1. What is the formula for force</li>
    <li style="margin-bottom:15px"> 
        <ul type="none">
            <li style="  font-size:20px; float:left"><input type="radio" name="q1op"/></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; float:left;" >Option 1</li>
            <li style=" font-size:20px; float:left; margin-left:30px"><input type="radio" name="q1op" /></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; float:left" >Option 2</li>
            <li style=" font-size:20px; float:left; margin-left:30px"><input type="radio" name="q1op" /></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; float:left" >Option 3</li>
            <li style=" font-size:20px; float:left; margin-left:30px"><input type="radio" name="q1op" /></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; margin-bottom:15px;" >Option 4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I know it can be done using javascript but I am not quite sure how do I do it, I have tried something:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function func(a) {
    if(a==1) {
        document.getElementById("mathematics").style.display="block";
    }
    if(a==2) {
        document.getElementById("physics").style.display="none";
    }
    if(a==3) {
        document.getElementById("chemistry").style.display="none";
    }
    if(a==4) {
        document.getElementById("biology").style.display="none";
    }
}
</script>
```

But it does not seem to work and I am really confused.

Comment: Put it on jsfiddle and I'll be glad to help you.

Comment: I'll let someone else answer your question, but just some pointers for your code... start using jQuery and never use inline styles.

Comment: I don't see any elements with the `ID`'s you are searching for..Are you getting confused with the `<form>` names?

Comment: @im1dermike, pretty bold statements.  I'd say adding jquery simply for element selection would be pretty dumb (which is really all he's doing).  And, while in this case I agree he could benefit from a CSS class, there's a time and a place for inline styles.

Comment: Please do run your code through some validators like W3C validator http://validator.w3.org/ and JSlint http://jslint.com/. These will be very helpful for your debugging and will solve your problems to a reasonable extent

Comment: @Tom: "Simplifying element selection... is pretty dumb".  OK... Also, there is never a time for inline styles in anything, but examples (but I would be the OP is using them in his production code).  Nothing bold about either statement.

Comment: @Urahara really...really sorry  some went horribly wrong with my home internet connection somehow I managed to fix it!!!                                              I have put the code in jsfiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/bijoy_xander/xy0tjynf/         hope you are not annoyed with me :)

Comment: The community have spoken and I haven't even started, yet you have page full of solutions :) goodluck.

Comment: Yah, well next time I'll make sure that I have a proper connection before I post a question :) Thank You

Comment: @BijoyJoseph I added a working live demo in my answer.

Comment: @R3tep well, I don't know how do I link JQuery in my page so that it could work. I tried this : <script  src="jquery.min.js"></script><script  src="hidden.js"></script>

Comment: @BijoyJoseph I am not sure that load a library (like jQuery), just for this, is the best way x) You have preserved the code of Jagadeesh?

Comment: @R3tep Yes..it worked this time...there was a small mistake in my linking code. I feel really embarrassing to be so stupid.   I really appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the ids to your forms

```
<form id='mathematics' name="first" style="display:none;">

<form id='physics' name="second" style="display:none;">

<form id='chemistry' name="third" style="display:none;">

<form id='biology' name="fourth" style="display:none;">
```

And changes your javascript to show/hide the selected form.

```
var d = document;
function $(id) {
   return d.getElementById(id);
}

function func(a) {
    var 
    mathDisplay  = $("mathematics"),
    physDisplay  = $("physics"),
    chemiDisplay = $("chemistry"),
    bioDisplay   = $("biology");

    (a == 1) ? ( mathDisplay.style.display  = "block" ) : ( mathDisplay.style.display  = "none" );
    (a == 2) ? ( physDisplay.style.display  = "block" ) : ( physDisplay.style.display  = "none" );
    (a == 3) ? ( chemiDisplay.style.display = "block" ) : ( chemiDisplay.style.display = "none" );
    (a == 4) ? ( bioDisplay.style.display   = "block" ) : ( bioDisplay.style.display   = "none" );

}
```

And sets the same name to your radios :

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" onclick="func(1)" />Mathematics
<input type="radio" name="radio" onclick="func(2)" />Physics
<input type="radio" name="radio" onclick="func(3)" />Chemistry
<input type="radio" name="radio" onclick="func(4)" />Biology
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xy0tjynf/3/)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to cache the elements into variable in function scope and use the variables? `var MATH = document.getElementsById("mathematics");
  var PHYSICS = document.getElementsById("physics");
  var CHEMSITRY = document.getElementsById("chemistry");
  var BIOLOGY = document.getElementsById("biology");` .. I am just curious

Comment: @Invent-Animate I see no better optimization now

Answer (score 1):

You're using getElementById() function whereas you dont have an id attribute. **change the name attribute to id**

Also make sure that the name attributes of all the radio buttons have the same value. If not, you will be able to select multiple radio buttons, which is not the intended purpose of radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

Demo link http://jsfiddle.net/dmxecnu8/

JSCODE

```
<script>$('.subject').click(function(){
            $('.form').hide()
            var selectedForm = "." + $(this).val()
            $(selectedForm).show()

        }) </script>
```

HTML CODE

```
<input type="radio" name="type" class="subject" value="first" /> Mathematics
<input type="radio" name="type" class="subject" value="second" /> Physics
<input type="radio" name="type" class="subject" value="third" /> Chemistry
<input type="radio" name="type" class="subject" value="fourth" /> Biology
<div id="content">
<p>Some contents</p>
<br /><br /><br />
<hr />
<div>
<form name="first"class="form first" style="display:none;">
<ul type="none">
<li style="margin-bottom:15px; font-size:20px">1. Maths</li>
    <li style="margin-bottom:15px"> 
        <ul type="none">
            <li style="  font-size:20px; float:left"><input type="radio" name="q1op"/></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; float:left;" >Option 1</li>
            <li style=" font-size:20px; float:left; margin-left:30px"><input type="radio" name="q1op" /></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; float:left" >Option 2</li>
            <li style=" font-size:20px; float:left; margin-left:30px"><input type="radio" name="q1op" /></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; float:left" >Option 3</li>
            <li style=" font-size:20px; float:left; margin-left:30px"><input type="radio" name="q1op" /></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; margin-bottom:15px;" >Option 4</li>
        </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</form>
<form name="second" class="form second" style="display:none">
<ul type="none">
    <li style="margin-bottom:15px; font-size:20px">1. Physics</li>
    <li style="margin-bottom:15px"> 
        <ul type="none">
            <li style="  font-size:20px; float:left"><input type="radio" name="q1op"/></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; float:left;" >Option 1</li>
            <li style=" font-size:20px; float:left; margin-left:30px"><input type="radio" name="q1op" /></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; float:left" >Option 2</li>
            <li style=" font-size:20px; float:left; margin-left:30px"><input type="radio" name="q1op" /></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; float:left" >Option 3</li>
            <li style=" font-size:20px; float:left; margin-left:30px"><input type="radio" name="q1op" /></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; margin-bottom:15px;" >Option 4</li>
        </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</form>
<form name="third" class="form third" style="display:none">
<ul type="none">
    <li style="margin-bottom:15px; font-size:20px">1. Chemistry</li>
    <li style="margin-bottom:15px"> 
        <ul type="none">
            <li style="  font-size:20px; float:left"><input type="radio" name="q1op"/></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; float:left;" >Option 1</li>
            <li style=" font-size:20px; float:left; margin-left:30px"><input type="radio" name="q1op" /></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; float:left" >Option 2</li>
            <li style=" font-size:20px; float:left; margin-left:30px"><input type="radio" name="q1op" /></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; float:left" >Option 3</li>
            <li style=" font-size:20px; float:left; margin-left:30px"><input type="radio" name="q1op" /></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; margin-bottom:15px;" >Option 4</li>
        </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</form>
<form name="fourth" class="form fourth" style="display:none">
<ul type="none">
    <li style="margin-bottom:15px; font-size:20px">1. Biology</li>
    <li style="margin-bottom:15px"> 
        <ul type="none">
            <li style="  font-size:20px; float:left"><input type="radio" name="q1op"/></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; float:left;" >Option 1</li>
            <li style=" font-size:20px; float:left; margin-left:30px"><input type="radio" name="q1op" /></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; float:left" >Option 2</li>
            <li style=" font-size:20px; float:left; margin-left:30px"><input type="radio" name="q1op" /></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; float:left" >Option 3</li>
            <li style=" font-size:20px; float:left; margin-left:30px"><input type="radio" name="q1op" /></li>
            <li style="font-size:20px; margin-bottom:15px;" >Option 4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</form>
```

I updated your code here. here is the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/dmxecnu8/

Comment: Hi Jagdeesh I tried the above code on my computer, it works fine on jsfiddle but it is not working on my system.

Comment: Did you include jquery? and i added some class names to radio buttons and modified name and value attributes. and added class name to forms also. Place the javascript code in the footer section and check the errors are there in console in chrome